# how can i get a class called MessagingService in java

Tags: java, android, class

i'm watching a tutorial about developing a chat Application in android and i have faced a problem in importing a class called 'MessagingService.java',

this class developed by google Inc, i searched many times and i couldn't find it.

Comment: This? http://developer.android.com/samples/MessagingService/src/com.example.android.messagingservice/MessagingService.html Found it by Googling "MessagingService.java" There is also a Github link here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ_7CCi5HMAhVDVD4KHaHABFIQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgooglesamples%2Fandroid-MessagingService%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FApplication%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fandroid%2Fmessagingservice%2FMessagingService.java&usg=AFQjCNG7iMm-grBeFRIFYSaW4x0P9VlpbA&sig2=-QzhirHMagvix3MDX-vfvw

Comment: no it isn't the one i need has a "copyright 2007" this is different

Comment: See my edited answer RE download link

Comment: Pls share the tutorial link

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d-_2gEwam4 on 2:37:35

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the project source from git.

Read the section titled [Import Samples from GitHub](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html).  That will tell you how to get a local copy of a sample project into Android Studio that you can play around with.

There is also a download link in the upper right hand corner of the page you referenced that will download the project to your machine.

Comment: give me anything about this class i have searched i github and can't find it

Comment: Why anyone would use Eclipse for Android development is beyond me.  You should switch to Android Studio.  Vastly superior in every way IMO.  Regardless, did you read the part of my answer that points you to the download link on the sample project page?  Click that and it will download a zip file with all the project files in it.

Comment: i'm using eclipse because android studio is very slow on my computer

Comment: i have downloaded the file from CubeJocky answer and i doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what else I can do to help.  You've got the file so maybe you need to open another question that address in more detail what "doesn't work" means in more detail.  Good luck

Comment: JJF thank you very much for your help i appreciate that, if you want more detailed look at this video 2:37:30
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d-_2gEwam4